# Issue passing token variable to header in Powershell

Tags: powershell

The $token variable value changes once it's passed to the header. How can I get the $token value remain the same once it's passed to the header? Thanks.

```
$body = @{
    username = "API"
    password = Read-Host "enter password" -MaskInput
    grant_type = "password"
};

$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://....../oauth2/token" -Method Post -Body $body
$token = $response.access_token;
return $token

$headers = @{
    Authorization = "Bearer $token"
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod "https://....../search-total" -Headers $headers
return $response;
```

Comment: Your return statement ends the execution before the $headers variable is set.

Comment: Move your `$headers` block above your `Invoke-RestMethod` request. Also, you dont appear to be passing the `$headers` into `Invoke-WebRequest`?

Comment: Is some code missing, or is this your actual script/function? `return` returns execution control to the caller, none of the code after the `return $token` statement will ever execute

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen I added the missing code. Thanks for taking a look.

Comment: @MisterSmith I added the missing code. Thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved by moving the return statement.